# How to substitute this chain of asynctasks and listeners with a Service?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application, when a user creates a product, I start a chain of db operations, network operations and file operations all connected to the activity and via listeners.
Although everything is in a separate AsyncTask, the UI Freezes.

I want to know how can I substitute this methodology with a Service that will take care of all of this in a background thread.

Here is some example code:

```
public interface OnLogInUserToServerListener {
    void onLoginUserToServerSuccess(User user);
    void onLoginUserToServerFailure(String error);
}

public interface OnInsertProductInDBListener {
    void onInsertProductInDBSuccess(int productId);
    void onInsertProductInDBFailure();

}

// The rest of the interfaces follow the same pattern


public class InsertProductInDBAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private OnInsertProductInDBListener listener;

    public InsertProductInDBAsync (OnInsertProductInDBListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

     boolean doInBackground {
         // do db insertion operation here
         return boolean;
     }

     void onPostExecute() {
          if(listener!=null) {
               if(boolean) {
                    listener.onInsertProductInDBSuccess():
                } else {
                    listener.onInsertProductInDBFailure();
                }

         }
     }
}

// The rest of the asynctasks follow the same pattern

public class CreateProductFragment extends Fragment implements OnLogInUserToServerListener, OnInsertProductInDBListener, OnUploadProductToServerListener, OnUploadProductImagesToServerListener {

    onCreateView {
        // some stuff 
        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(... {

             onClick {
                 new InsertProductInDBAsync(,,,CreateProductFragment.this).execute(); // this is passed as a listener (this fragment is the listener)
             }

        }

    } // End of onCreateView


    @Override
    onInsertProductInDBSuccess(int productId) {
        new LogInUserOnServerAsync(,,,this).execute(); // this is passed as a listener (this fragment is the listener)

    }

    @Override
    onInsertProductInDBFailure() { ... }

    @Override
    onLoginUserOnServerSuccess(User user) {
        new UploadProductOnServerAsync(,,,this).execute():
    }

    @Override
    onLoginUserOnServerFailure() { ... }

    @Override
    onUploadProductOnServerSuccess(int productServerId) {

          for(ProductImage image : product.getImages() {
              image.setProductServerId(productServerId);
              new UpdateProductInDB(product, new OnUpdateProductInDBListener             { 


             @Override
             onUpdateProductInDBSuccess() {
                   new UploadProductImageToServerAsync().execute();
             }

            ... }

              ).execute():
          }

    }
```

}

Now, how do I implement this as a service that will run entirely in the background and not hold on to the fragment at all?

Comment: Service doesn't handle threading for you, please read documentation. From what you say I don't see anything wrong with architecture. But Service won't definitely solve all your problems. Try to find what's wrong with your code.

Comment: to add to @Mighter's comment, a service will still run on the UI/main thread. the only advantage to a service is that it's lifecycle is not tied to your Activity. Also, why are you chaining together these instead of just using a single AsyncTask? Every time you come back into main and then create a new asynctask, you're forcing a context switch. On a phone with 1 core this is pretty expensive, and regardless is prone to multiplying the idiosyncrasies of asynctask.

Comment: @SamDozor if I put this all in a single AsyncTask will the UI freezing stop? Sometimes I cannot leave the fragment before all of this is ended

Comment: A single asynctask will help things ultimately move quicker. Still, your UI shouldn't be freezing unless what you're doing in your background threads is REALLY intensive. I suspect you're doing something on the main thread that you shouldn't be - you should profile the Fragment to see what's causing the freeze: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: I'd suggest that you read documentation and tutorials about AsyncTask once again and get back to us with specific questions. Problems like "my app doesn't work" are hard to solve without being certified telepath.

Comment: I want to know how to use a service in cases like this.